# Are parameter names part of an Ethereum contract API?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, evm

If I change the names of method parameters in a public API of an Ethereum contract, will this break any caller's ability to call that API?

The reason I ask is that I frequently see hashes of method signatures used for various purposes, and they seem to often include parameter names (e.g. the method hashes in EIP2612).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signature "includes" the name of the method and a complete list of parameters TYPES. The NAMES of the parameters do not affect the signature.